Making 'python setup.py sdist' don't rename pkg name in PKG-INFO
my setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='py_lib',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=["py_lib"],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    description=''
)

when run python setup.py sdist, the py_lib.egg-info/PKG_INFO is:
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: py-lib
Version: 0.0.0
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: 

I hope Name is py_lib, how to do

Since generating egg files are depreciated as of now I recommend using a pyproject.toml and using build utilities to create python wheels  https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects.

py_lib is equivalent to py-lib.
Read the Python Packaging Guide - name normalization

The name should be lowercased with all runs of the characters ., -, or _ replaced with a single - character.

i.e. all of the following valid names are equivalent and will be normalized to friendly-bard:

Friendly-Bard
FRIENDLY-BARD
friendly.bard
friendly_bard
friendly--bard


"py_lib is equivalent to py-lib." Only at PyPI and similar indices but not outside of python package index hostings. If you have a file py_lib.whl (or an URL to such a file) you cannot install it with pip install ./py-lib.whl.
